# will my internet be drained with 2 networks?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, hotspot, tethering

currently im connecting to the internet using hotspot from my personal phone, which uses wifi to transmit internet, i'm also currently using spacedesk with my old phone with usb tether connection (this phone doesnt have any internet in it) so i have 2 internet connections: 1 ethernet, offline and 1 wifi, online, im connecting to spacedesk using the ethernet (my old phone isnt connected to my main hotspot) the question i have is will internet be drained off my main hotspot?

edit:  spacedesk requires a local network connection which is achieved by either bluetooth, wifi or tethered connection, i have connected my pc to the internet using the hotspot (wifi connection) of my main phone) and connected my secondary phone to the pc with tether connection (usb) so i'm connected to the ethernet which is offline and my wifi (hotspot) which is online. what im saying is if i run spacedesk on my secondary phone with tether on my pc, will my internet on my main phone be drained

Comment: If you are referring to [spacedesk](https://www.spacedesk.net/), I would assume that the tethered phone would use the network connection of the PC it's attached to (if Spacedesk is even using a network connection). But you may wish to [edit] your question to explain in detail what you're doing and why you think this may cause issues with your internet or other network connections.

Comment: Sorry, but this is just stream-of-consciousness. We cannot see over your shoulder to see what you're trying to achieve. Take a deep breath… tell us exactly what you are doing, what happens, what you think should happen, & detail the difference between the two.

Comment: @Anaksunaman spacedesk requires a local network connection which is achieved by either bluetooth, wifi or tethered connection, i have connected my pc to the internet using the hotspot (wifi connection) of my main phone) and connected my secondary phone to the pc with tether connection (usb) so i'm connected to the ethernet which is offline and my wifi (hotspot) which is online. what im saying is if i run spacedesk on my secondary phone with tether on my pc, will my internet on my main phone be drained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have connected my PC to the internet using the hotspot (WiFi connection) of my main phone and connected my secondary phone to the PC with a tether connection (USB). [If] I run [spacedesk](https://www.spacedesk.net/) on my secondary phone via tether on my PC, will my internet on my main phone be drained?

As far as I am aware, tethering a device directly to a PC is typically a closed loop between the device and the PC itself and should not need an internet connection to function:

[image: Flowchart]

**Caveats**

- Though it may not affect your overall hotspot bandwidth or data caps, it's theoretically possible that communications between your secondary phone and the PC could slow down the connection between your PC and the internet, simply because the PC network card has more data to process (i.e. transferring images). But you'd have to test this for yourself.
- Connections to devices outside your local network (e.g. "Remote Display", above) would require an internet connection to function and would likely affect your bandwidth and data caps to some degree.
- If the software decided to "phone home" periodically (e.g. for update information), this would use an internet connection.

Comment: sorry for the late answer but this seems to work, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you found this answer useful. =)